# Array Index Out of Bound in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-handling

```
package com.testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CsvParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "D:/code-home/SentimentAnalysis/test_data/Sentiment Analysis Dataset.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "\t";

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            // use comma as separator
            String []tweet = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            System.out.println(tweet[1]);
            System.out.println(tweet[3]);
        }
    }
```

The program's purpose is to parse the CSV format. I have used bufferRead method.

When I go to compile the program, it works fine. When I run the program, I get an error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.testing.CsvParser.main(CsvParser.java:34)
```

Comment: Did you try to print the `line` you are attempting to split? Usually CSV files use a comma separator, not `\t` (CSV = Comma Separated Values).

Comment: What content you have in the file? show sample

Comment: The program is just telling you in your file, when you split it by tabulations ("\t"), there are not enough to access to the 2nd slot (tweet[1]). Check your file!

Comment: please upload sample file

Comment: See comment in your program `// use comma as separator`

Comment: i had a data set that is separated by  a tab so I used "\t".

Comment: it prints all the values of tweet[1] and tweet[2] then after only there is a exception handling error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a comma separator.

Change

```
String cvsSplitBy = "\t";
```

to

```
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
```